# Pass data between two activities in android

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, runtime

I made an android app which passes data between two activities but an error occurs in my code that I can't discover.
First "activity_main.xml" executes, and when the user presses a button, a second activity "activity_main1.xml" starts. But when the button is pressed, an error occurs and app stops.

This is the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.measureregistertool;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
}
```

This is the activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Take Photo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the activity_main1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.measureregistertool"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.measureregistertool.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

[My code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDmju.png)

Comment: Can you give the code of the onClick method when the button is pressed? The error seems to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the second Activity (MainActivity1) in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
android:name="com.example.measureregistertool.MainActivity1"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second activity is missing in the manifest file. You probably created it just by creating new java class, not by creator from right click.
Add it to the manifest below your activity tag

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.measureregistertool.MainActivity1">
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two activities in your package,But have only declared one in manifest.
Declare the other Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Always create activity by File->new->Activity -> (Select Category).
This process performs three operations

```
1. Create Activity java file.
2. Create Layout xml file.
3. Register your Activity class in Manifest file.
```

So you can be safe from such problems.